# searching in a html table using angular js

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html table.i already bind the table using angular js

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-controller="InboxMailCtrl">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" ng-model="search" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                Search
            </button>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover table-mail">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="CU in InboxList">
                    <td class="mail-ontact"><a href="" ng-click="ViewEmailDetails(CU.InboxMailID)">{{CU.Reciever}}</a></td>
                    <td class="mail-subject"><a href="" ng-click="ViewEmailDetails(CU.InboxMailID)">{{CU.Subject}}</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

here is my angularjs code.i want to add search functionality

```
var InboxDraftMailCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
    BindDraftMailList();

function BindDraftMailList(Data) {
    debugger
    var UserEmail = sessionStorage.getItem("loginUserID");
    var obj = {
        data: UserEmail
    }
    debugger
    $http({
        url: "MailRoute/getDataForDraftMail",
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: obj,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).success(function (response) {

    })
           .error(function (error) {
               alert(error);
           });
}
```

what i have add to achieve the search functionality

Comment: Clearly didn't try a simple web search for simple terms like `angular search` or would have found **[filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** and lots of other results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter method of angularJS. Filter method selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.
Write html code as.

```
 <body ng-app>
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-controller="InboxMailCtrl">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" ng-model="search" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            Search
        </button>
     </div>
     <table class="table table-hover table-mail">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="CU in InboxList| filter:search">
                <td class="mail-ontact"><a href="" ng-click="ViewEmailDetails(CU.InboxMailID)">{{CU.Reciever}}</a></td>
                <td class="mail-subject"><a href="" ng-click="ViewEmailDetails(CU.InboxMailID)">{{CU.Subject}}</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

This link will be helpful in solving your problem. [link](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/searchtable)

Comment: Doesn't provide explanation of why you would do this

Comment: Ok. I will provide it. actually i am updating my answer.

Comment: Well, at least what I understand the question is that he wants to use a search button to make a http.post requisition server-side and fetch the e-mails that match with the term searched. If so, your answer is incorrect. On other hand he didn't explain well what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're looking to filter the already fetched results, assuming that the search method is /MailRoute/getDataForDraftMail, you're looking to do something like this:

```
var InboxDraftMailCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {

      $scope.Search = function(){
      $http({
      url: "MailRoute/getDataForDraftMail",
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      data: obj,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }}).success(function (response) {

        // Fetch what you want from response
        $scope.InboxList = response.data.emails; // Something like this
    })//. etc
}
```

And in the html button click should be:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="Search();" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        Search
 </button>
```